# How to include a relation of a relation in an AppMaker table field?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have three data models, Partner, Client and SOW, where Client is a one-to-many relation to SOW, and Partner is a one-to-many relation to Client. I would like to include Partner Name as a column in a table displaying SOWs. Is there a way to do this with a datasource query script? Or a different approach altogether? 
I was able to add a label to the SOW table row that is data bound to the Partner name via relation, but I have yet to tackle sorting and filtering by Partner, and this method appears to fetch Partner real-time after the table loads. I am currently using Drive Tables as my datasource, but am open to switching to Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually add header and 'cell'(one more label in list row).

Binding for the label in the header:

`@models.Partner.fields.Name.displayName`

Binding for the label in the list row:

`@datasource.item.Client.Partner.Name`

And don't forget to add both `Client` and `Client.Partner` relations to [Prefetch](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#prefetch), it should make your page load/render faster.

**Useful tip:**

You can copy/paste existing table labels to duplicate all original margins/paddings/styles and make them look/behave in the same way as all other labels within the table. In this case you'll need just to adjust your bindings and maybe rename some things.

**Note:**

Most likely you'll not be able to sort your table by relation of relation, but feel free to try(checkout `onClick` event handlers of labels in the table header).

Comment: Thanks! Your binding for the label in the row is MUCH simpler than mine. I was climbing up and down widget parents/children. Your useful tip is also very handy!