# How many levels deep can App Maker relationships be accessed?

Tags: google-app-maker

This is a follow-up question to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820165/how-to-include-a-relation-of-a-relation-in-an-appmaker-table-field). In App Maker, if one has Model called Contacts, with a relational field called Owner (which refers to another Contact record within the Contact Model), how many levels deep can be accessed by a widget?

Could you have @datasource.item.Contact.Owner.Owner.Owner.Owner etc, to be able to show the contact and its owners many levels up?

Comment: How many do you need?

Comment: Maybe 4-5 levels.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no any limitation from browser side. I tried to create heavily nested object in Chrome and it allowed me to add 300K+ nesting levels and ate 5Gb+ of memory for that single object, before UI got frozen and tab died.

Taking into account that App Maker's objects are way more complex than my test one `{ x: { x: { x: { ... } } } }`, we can be super conservative and lets say that browser can survive 1K+ nesting levels. So, you see there should not be limitation on browser side in case you'll load relations in ***async*** manner (explicitly by `item._loadRelationName()` or implicitly using bindings).

In case you want to load all those nested records at once using [prefetches](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#prefetch) then we need to find out how many joins MySQL allows to make. According to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246413) it is somewhere about 60. [Drive Tables](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/drivetables) is a separate story, maybe if I have some time I'll dig into it and try to find its limitations.